# Present continuous vs present perfect to describe a trend

Tags: grammar

If I have to write an article about housing price trend for a newspaper:

I don’t know what is the difference between:

(1) The house prices **are decreasing**, so people is trying to buy one in this time.

(2) The house prices **have been decreasing**, so people are trying to buy one in this time.

Answer (score 1):

Your two sentences have different meanings.

- "Prices are decreasing" = right now, at this present time, they are decreasing.
- "Prices have been decreasing" = that's a historical pattern in the past, right up to today -- perhaps they will continue to decrease, but that's a question of economics, not grammar!
- "Prices had been decreasing" = the prices *were* decreasing but then it stopped, and we're looking back from a later time, historically

Examples, perhaps more helpful:

- Prices are decreasing, and we don't know what to do!
- Prices have been decreasing all month, but we think they might improve next week.
- Prices had been decreasing last year until the government intervened.

Comment: Does the sentence with present perfect continuous also imply that the price is also decreasing now.?

Comment: "Has been" means that it might be continuing. "Had been" means that it's ended, over, not continuing any more.